# IronPython 3.4 with dotnet 6 facing problem

Tags: python, c#, ironpython

I am trying to create a sample dll with a function that adds two integer.
I created a dll for that.

Process to create the dll ===>
Used VS2022 and created dll with .Net core6
sample code used

```
namespace NewTest
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public int Get_sum(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }
    }
}
```

the dll is  created in NewTest\bin\Release\net6.0\NewTest.dll

I have installed the IronPython3.4

C:\CallFromPython\ClassLibrary3\bin\Release>ipy --version
IronPython 3.4.1

C:\CallFromPython\ClassLibrary3\bin\Release>python --version
Python 3.10.11

Then I have created the python file with below content

```
import clr
import os
import sys
import timeit
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
#print(sys.path)
clr.AddReference("NewTest.dll")
```

But i am getting some error like below

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "callcsharpdll.py", line 7, in 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Please help in solving this  problem. Iron python documentation is not enough mention about how to use the dotnet dll in ipy.